# Dynamically Pull Data from Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: c#, php, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm a PHP Developer that recently got introduced to Dynamics CRM Online as I am building an application that needs to pull Customer details directly from a Dynamics CRM Online account to populate a Customer selection list.

I've gone through a number of options including: 
http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2012/08/php-to-crm-online-easy-way-to-do.html

But I was unable to authenticate at all. According to the blogger, Tanguy, MS has since changed and the solution he posted is no longer valid. I am unable to locate a new solution for connect.

I've even tried the Dynamics SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) but I've never done C# coding so I'm at a lost and it seems the samples weren't even compiling anyway. At the same time, I'm not sure this tool was even meant for pulling data from Dynamics CRM Online or the user hosted version.

If there's anyone who can help, it would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to figure this out for days and trying various options only to continually hit dead end after dead end.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion in this situation is always to create a C# Web Service that will act as a bridge between CRM and your php code.

The Web Service use `.NET` so can easily pull the data from CRM, and because is a Web Service you can consume it by any platform (with `SOAP` or `REST` is your decision)

Comment: I will certainly give it a shot Guido. Hopefully it works though as I said my .NET knowledge is very very limited. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have been working through a CRM Online - PHP connector for the last few months. I have no server to host C# code so i've been restricted to connecting to CRM using PHP.

I have managed to get Office 365 and Windows Live authentication working (in the near future all Windows Live users will be migrated to Office 365). I have been starting to document my process here.

http://crmtroubleshoot.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/dynamics-crm-2011-php-and-soap-using.html

After spending a fair bit of time on this connection I find myself agreeing with Guido Preite. If you are in a position to host a C# Web Service somewhere then this is probably worthwhile.