# CRM Dynamics and Java Integration error

Tags: java, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm new to CRM dynamics, and I'm trying to connect my Java Web Service to CRM Dynamics, but after following this tutorial >> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979.aspx I'm getting this error:

```
The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
```

I have no idea how to solve this.  If someone had this problem before, and was able to help me, I'll be very grateful.

This error occurs when I try to run the test code available at the Microsoft link.

Comment: please provide more details (version of crm, onpremise or online, code you already tested, authentication used, ...) and I suggest also this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/16897882/2191473

Comment: I haven't done any Java - CRM stuff however the error suggests that a module called 'addressing' isn't included. I would be confirming that all references are available.  It doesn't look like a Dynamics CRM related error.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Dynamics CRM problem.

It appears to be an issue with Axis2.

You are missing either a reference or the actual .mar file i'm guessing.

This issue seems to be similar
[How do I use WS-Addressing properly in an Axis2 client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526012/how-do-i-use-ws-addressing-properly-in-an-axis2-client)

This issue again seems to be similar however does not appear to be resolved. However perhaps you confirm the files mentioned can be found?
http://axis.8716.n7.nabble.com/Deploying-axis2-in-tomcat-6-td37788.html